# Горелина. Значение слова

Tags: словарь

И ещё один вопрос из того же списка: что такое "горелина"? Мне вот кажется, что это горелое дерево, но в словарях я этого слова не обнаружил.

Контекст: Уже на подходе к норе остановил её запах едкого пряного дыма. И иное время тотчас повернула бы она, скрылась незаметно, теперь же оставался в норе её последний щенок, и она не могла уйти, словно привязанная. Тихо-тихо скользила она меж берёз и ёлочек, инстинктом выбирая подветренную сторону. Вот и чёрная горелина, склон родимой горушки...

Ещё контекст: Никто не знал, сколько лет торчала чёрная горелина над елями и осинами, сколько молний воткнулось летними грозами в её зубастый излом, сколько вывелось птичек, сколько листьев сгнило в пустом колодце сердцевины и от скольких морозов родилась её звонкость, чтобы с первым тёплом чёртовым звоном гудеть над мшарой...

Answer (score 2):

По контексту трудно предположить иное значение. Но слово явно "авторское", словарям не может быть известное. Есть специальные словари диалектизмов, может там есть что-то. 
Но больше всего похоже на авторское изобретение.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что за "список", без контекста слово понять трудно. Скорее всего - фамилия. Или опечатка "горели на".

Насчет значения "горелое дерево" - сомневаюсь крепко. Есть слова *горельник, гарь, горелом(?)*... Куда еще эту странно звучащую "балерину"? Хотя, в принципе, все может быть. Диалектизмы - вещь необъятная.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, без контекста трудно понять.

Дополнение

Вот что удалось найти в корпусе р.я. 1909 ― 1910 ― чернорабочий на фабрике Яковлева в Костромской губернии, на фабрике *Горелина* в Иваново-Вознесенске, в имении "Осипово" в Вологде, на заводах "Невский", "Тентелевский" и Комендантском аэродроме Петербурга. ***(Феликс Чуев. Ильюшин (1998) ).***

Разрешите относительно тысячного оклада. Вышло так, что в это время повышение ставок на дороговизну шло автоматически. Но я с 500 руб. , получаемых у ***Горелина,*** перешел в Москвотоп на 400 рублей. Меня не смущала эта материальная потеря, потому что был одинокий. Крыленко. Вы перешли под влиянием Кирша? (***Процесс членов ЦК контрреволюционной организации "Промышленная партия" (1930) // "Известия" 1930.12.01)***.

Comment: Контекст добавлен.

Comment: Серж, в ваших примерах (фабрика Горелина) - обычна фамилия Горелин, весьма распространенная. родительный падеж, Фабрика - чья.  
Упоминать здесь имена собственные нет большого смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Интересное слово! - надо запомнить

По аналогии о деревьях:

**Дубовина** ж. пск. дубовое корье, для дупленья кож.

**Дубовина** об. дубина, дурак, дуралей.

**Кленовина** ы, ж. Брус, бревно, ствол срубленного клена.

Всем спасибо!!!